# Is htmlspecialchars() used for all applications when suspect content is put on a page?

Tags: php, xss, html-entities

I understand that I should use `htmlspecialchars()` when displaying user provided content as HTML on a page.  Does that apply for other content such as JavaScript, CSS, value of an `<INPUT>`, etc?  I believe I have heard some to say use `json_encode()` instead of `htmlspecialchars()` to encode JS.

```
<?php
$dangerous=$_GET['dangerous'];
session_start();
$_SESSION['mySession']=$dangerous;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <title><?php echo($dangerous);?></title>  
        <style type="text/css">
        div.<?php echo($dangerous);?> {size:12px;}
        </style> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var myVar=<?php echo($dangerous);?>; 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        echo(<?php echo($dangerous);?>)
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo($dangerous);?>" class="whatEver" name="myInput" />
        <a href="<?php echo($dangerous);?>">Some Link</a>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that I should use htmlspecialchars() when displaying user provided content as HTML on a page. Does that apply for other content such as JavaScript, CSS, value of an `<INPUT>`, etc?

Err… sort of.

First, that assumes that you are intending to accept *text* (which you will then represent as HTML). If you are accepting HTML then you need to use a different approach to sanitising it (this usually involves using a real HTML parser and a whitelist of acceptable elements and attributes, and then possibly additional checking of attribute values).

If we carry of with the assumption that we are working with text…

The value of an input element is provided by an HTML attribute. HTML attributes contain HTML so you need to represent special characters inside the value with entities.

CSS and JavaScript are not HTML, so you need to use appropriate escaping for the target language. However, you then embed (presumably) the CSS or JavaScript into an HTML document.

If you are putting it in an attribute value, then you need to escape it as normal.

If you are putting it into a `<script>` or `<style>` element, then you have to deal with their special handling rules in HTML. Those elements are defined as containing CDATA (if we put it in HTML 4 terms) so the only thing you have to watch out for is the presence of `</script>` or `</style>` in the data.

If you are dealing with XHTML (and I suggest you don't) then you have to jump through the usual hoops described in [the Media Types Note](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/).

Comment: Thanks Quentin.  Yes, accepting text (I use htmlpurifier for HTML).  So, any text on the screen as well as HTML attributes, I will use `htmlspecialchar()`.  I will look into using CDATA for JavaScript.  I really have no use for adding it to CSS, but just included the question for completeness.  And, no I am not using XHTML.

Comment: What about `$('#myID').text(data.dangerous);` or the same for `html()` where `data` was provided via Ajax and came from a DB?

Comment: Then the data is being converting from "content of HTTP request" to "text" by XMLHttpRequest (so that's safe), and is being converted from "text" to "an html representation of text" by jQuery so (baring bugs in jQuery that are really unlikely given how long the feature has been around) that's safe too.

Comment: Thanks again Quentin.  I understand that I do NOT need to use `htmlspecialchar()` server side.  If I misunderstood you, please advise.